# Multiple React App Containers with External Reverse Proxy

Tags: reactjs, docker, express, nginx, docker-compose

**Edit 2:** Okay I take back the "entirely" part. I started having issues again and found that it's due to the "cache assets" toggle on the main reverse proxy config panel in NPM. With it on, I successfully get manifest.json but 404 on everything else (including resources in the same folder); with it off, this doesn't happen. The 404s happen even if I clear cache and hard reload in my browser or use incognito mode.

**Edit:** After almost losing my mind I now realized this was entirely due to user error :)

My custom location in Nginx Proxy Manager (NPM) was set as "/app2" and I thought the right thing to do was navigating to [www.example.com/app2](http://www.example.com/app2) but it turns out the routing only works if you navigate to [www.example.com/app2/](http://www.example.com/app2/)

Alternatively, I [set the location to "/app2/"](https://imgur.com/a/GkHnrzr) with the trailing "/" and now can successfully navigate to either [www.example.com/app2/](http://www.example.com/app2/) or [www.example.com/app2](http://www.example.com/app2)

I found that having `"homepage": "."` in my app2-frontend container's package.json is fine, and that I needed to remember to pre-pend any fetches on the api with "." e.g. `fetch("./api/stuff")`

The nginx.conf I ended up using in the app2-frontend container is unchanged from below.

**Original Post:**

What I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to use the [react-express-mysql awesome-compose](https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/tree/master/react-express-mysql) as a framework for setting up multiple react apps that are tied to the same domain. Once dev is complete, I update the Dockerfile for the frontend to add in Nginx and have Nginx serve the frontend so that it is not running using npm start.  I additionally am using [Nginx Proxy Manager](https://nginxproxymanager.com/) as a reverse proxy to route where I need and manage SSL termination for me.

I want to be able to:

- Access App 1 at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
- Access App 2 at [www.example.com/app](http://www.example.com/app)

Docker environment wise these are the containers I'm working with:

```
[Reverse Proxy]
- NPM         Container = nginx-proxy-manager

[App 1]
- Frontend    Container = app1-frontend
- Backend     Container = app1-backend
- DB          Container = app1-db
[App 2]
- Frontend    Container = app2-frontend
- Backend     Container = app2-backend
- DB          Container = app2-db
```

Networking wise, the Docker containers look like this:

```
[nginx-proxy-manager]
Networks: 
    app1-public app2-public
Port Mapping (host:container): 
    80:80 
    443:443

[app1-frontend]
Networks: 
    app1-public
Port Mapping (host:container): 
    NONE

[app1-backend]
Networks:
    app1-public
    app1-private
Port Mapping (host:container): 
    NONE

[app1-db]
Networks: 
    app1-private
Port Mapping (host:container): 
    NONE

[app2-frontend]
Networks: 
    app2-public
Port Mapping (host:container): 
    NONE

[app2-backend]
Networks: 
    app2-public 
    app2-private
Port Mapping (host:container): 
    NONE

[app2-db]
Networks: 
    app2-private
Port Mapping (host:container): 
    NONE
```

The frontend containers' nginx .conf looks the same for both apps. The Dockerfiles for the front/back end containers set the alias of each to "frontend" or "backend" specifically so that the proxy_pass functions within each app's public network.

```
events {
    worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024 
} 
http { 
    server { 
        listen 3000; 
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types; root /var/www; index index.html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /api/ {
            resolver 127.0.0.11;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://backend:80/;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is with routing [www.example.com/app](http://www.example.com/app) to App 2.

In Nginx Proxy Manager I am able to reach both apps no problem if I have one as [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and the other as app2.example.com... but if I set up app2 as a custom location under the proxy for app1, I get 404 errors related to some static build .js files. It looks to me like the issue is that the "server" is always App 1 and nothing beyond the index.html on the app2 frontend container is shared with the browser.

NPM settings:

[Base proxy going to App 1](https://imgur.com/a/FUEqjEn)

[Custom location going to App 2](https://imgur.com/a/B6Q7Z61)

The error I'm getting specifically is this [404 related to static .js files](https://imgur.com/a/5B439Xw)

I've tried a few different custom configurations in Nginx Proxy Manger, as well as attempting to re-direct within the "base" app's Nginx conf but the main issue remains the same in that the App 2 specific .js files give 404 errors.